# Windows Azure cloud service resource usage with RDP enabled

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-worker-roles

How does enabling RDP on Windows Azure cloud service instances affect them? Do they consume significantly less resources with RDP disabled? Are they running in server core mode?

Answer (score 0):

Just enabling of RDP does little for performance/resources/badwidth of a VM.

However, when you actually connect to RDP on a server, there is a certain amount of bandwidth, RAM and CPU cycles that is now drawn away from the server to support the desktop experience for RDP'ed user.  It is not super significant, but it does exist.  It is hard to predict "how much" that is, as it depends on the activity of the RDP'ed user.

HTH

Comment: Yes, I understand that with the same configuration of OS, difference should be very small. Still I assumed if RDP is disabled, the VM would run on a server core version of OS..

Comment: RDP being enabled or disabled does mean that a different SKU of the OS is deployed.  The same SKU is deployed in Azure, regardless of the flag.  In fact, you can later on enable or disable RDP via powershell and it's just a service start on the VM and not a full re-build of the Role.